# C# listview in winforms not displaying added items

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am trying to select a directory from an open file dialog in C# but when I actually add the items to the List View, it is not being displayed. THis is my code so far... am I missing something?

```
private void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog folderPicker = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            listLeft.View = View.Details;
            if (folderPicker.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPicker.SelectedPath);
                FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
                DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories();

                foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories)
                {
                    listLeft.Items.Add("Directory " + directory.Name);
                }
                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                {
                    listLeft.Items.Add(file.Name);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:::
Added this screenshot with descriptions...
[image]

Comment: show us the output please

Comment: Love this. SO needs more drawn on screen shots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that listLeft is your ListView. You need to add subitems like this:

```
            foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
                lvi.SubItems.Add("Directory " + directory.Name);
                listLeft.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem();
                lvi.SubItems.Add(file.Name);
                listLeft.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
```

**EDIT: Try this:**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        listLeft.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader());
        FolderBrowserDialog folderPicker = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        listLeft.View = View.Details;
        if (folderPicker.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPicker.SelectedPath);
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();
            DirectoryInfo[] directories = di.GetDirectories();

            foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directories)
            {
                listLeft.Items.Add("Directory " + directory.Name);
            }
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                listLeft.Items.Add(file.Name);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Comment: This still just produces the same output... no visible adds. please see my edit.. i have added a screenshot

Comment: Does it make any difference if you set the RootFolder property of folderPicker explicitly first? If you attach a debugger can you see it looping your directory structure correctly?

Comment: yes it seems to work perfectly.... I just dont know why I cannot see the actual added items. its there in code but not visible in winform

Comment: That is strange. If you delete the listbox from the form and re-add does that make any difference? I am thinking that there is a visual property set on it that you don't want. If you examine the listLeft.Items property is it populated as expected in the debugger?

Comment: You do have columns added to your ListView don't you?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not working either. yes it works fine... exactly as I want it. at the end I can even hover over the items in code while debugging and I see them there just as I want it, but no visible stuff after everything is done.

Comment: Add listLeft.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader()); just inside the top of your try... block to see if that makes a difference. No columns are added by default to listview control

Comment: Yes, this is it! Its displaying now. Thank you:)

Comment: Note that you will want to move the line listLeft.Columns.Add(new ColumnHeader()); otherwise it will keep creating columns every time you click the button. Just set it in properties on the control and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

It should be adding to the listbox - if there are objects in the directories and files objects... try setting a breakpoint in each method and seeing what happens. If the breakpoints aren't triggered then something is wrong with your Get() methods...

Comment: Everything works fine. its just not displaying the items. it IS being added to the listview. just dont know why I am not able to see them in the end result

Answer (score -4):

your question states 'listview in winforms'.

But a System.Windows.Forms.ListBox does not have View property, so your line of code

```
listLeft.View = View.Details;
```

does not compile when I try to reproduce.

Are you perhaps referring to a WPF listbox instead?
In that case, can you show us more code, in particular your data binding?

Comment: listView not listBox, please delete the answer

Comment: This surely is a ListView